# Informix Stored Procedures with Entity Framework Issue

Tags: entity-framework, informix

I am trying to import stored procedure into the entity model using database first approach and import fails due to the following warning. I am using Visual Studio 2015 update3

**Error 6005:** *The funtion 'ar_get_contact_name' has a return data type 'varchar' that is currently not supported for the target Entity Framework version. The function was excluded.*

**Error 6046:** Unable to generate function import return type of the store function 'ar_get_contact_name'. The function will be ignored and the function import will not be generated.

***Table and SP as follows***

*create table "entityframework".ar_contact
  (
    contact_code char(10) not null primary key,
    name char(80) not null
  );*

CREATE PROCEDURE 'entityframework'.ar_get_contact_name ( 
cont_code LIKE ar_contact.contact_code)

RETURNING
VARCHAR(50);

DEFINE cont_name VARCHAR(255);

SELECT 
    ar_contact.name
  INTO
    cont_name
  FROM 
    ar_contact
  WHERE 
    cont_code = contact_code;

RETURN cont_name;

END PROCEDURE

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Truly Informix do not have a good story with Entity Framework (EF) Support yet.
Right now for .net application to use EF functionality they have to use DB2 driver connection to Informix using DRDA protocol. 
While using the DB2 EF driver connecting to Informix database, many of the functionality work ok (but not all).
Certain functionalities are different at database level for DB2 and Informix.
The return value of store procedures and functions are one of such difference; very likely you may be getting into this difference.

Comment: Have you ever try to import informix sps in to EF?